# ActiveMQ negative AverageEnqueueTime

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I'm facing a strange issue on a network of brokers, with AMQ 5.8.0.
Checking the times on Jconsole I can see negative AverageEnqueueTime values.
The same applies querying such values in a programmatic way using the following code:

```
String jmxUrl = "service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://" + myBrokerUri + ":1098/jmxrmi"; 
JMXServiceURL url = new JMXServiceURL(jmxUrl); 
JMXConnector connector = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(url, null); 
connector.connect(); 
MBeanServerConnection connection = connector.getMBeanServerConnection(); 
TopicViewMBean topicMbean = (TopicViewMBean) MBeanServerInvocationHandler.newProxyInstance(connection, 
                                                            myTopicName, TopicViewMBean.class, true); 
topicMbean.getAverageEnqueueTime();
```

Using just one broker, in the very same enviornment, I can see the right values (positive and meaningful).

Any idea about this?

Thank you very much

Best

cghersi